# Copy Style/Format of one cell to another cell Excel Interop C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to copy Cell format/Style to another cell
Just like "Format Painter" option in Excel application

Here is what I have tried but didnt worked

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Style HeaderStyle = null;

SxlSheetRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlTamplateWorkSheet.UsedRange[rowCnt, colCnt];
DxlSheetRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlTamplateWorkSheet.UsedRange[DrowCnt, DcolCnt];

HeaderStyle = SxlSheetRange.Style;

DxlSheetRange.Style = HeaderStyle;
```

I dont want to copy just want to style the cell just like the "Format Painter" option in Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is PasteSpecial method.
For example:

```
//Copies cell C3
Range cellToCopy = (Range)activeWorksheet.Cells[3, 3];
cellToCopy.Copy();

//Paste format only to the cell C5
Range cellToPaste = (Range)activeWorksheet.Cells[5, 3];
cellToPaste.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats);
```

*Tip: You can record a macro on Excel and have a look at the code for the macro and use that code logic in C#

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to go about it, reading and writing values (including styles) as XML. You would need to expand it to make it handle ranges larger than one cell, but consider it a proof of concept:

```
using NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = NetOffice.ExcelApi;

namespace _43248441
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var app = Excel.Application.GetActiveInstance())
            {
                var workbook = app.ActiveWorkbook;
                var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

                var range1 = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
                var range2 = sheet.Cells[1, 3];

                //our range is only 1 cell in this case, so we get the first cell and its style
                var xml1 = (string)range1.get_Value(rangeValueDataType: XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet);
                var doc1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace); //Make sure to preserve whitespace
                var firstCell1 = doc1.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.LocalName == "Cell");
                var style1 = GetStyleForCell(firstCell1, doc1);


                //same here
                var xml2 = (string)range2.get_Value(rangeValueDataType: XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet);
                var doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                var firstCell2 = doc2.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.LocalName == "Cell");
                var style2 = GetStyleForCell(firstCell2, doc2);

                //check if the second XDocument already contains a style with the same name as the first cell's
                var sameStyle2 = GetStyleById(doc2, style1.Item2);

                var style2container = style2.Item1.Parent;

                //remove the style if it exists
                if (sameStyle2 != null)
                    sameStyle2.Remove();

                //add a clone of cell1's style
                style2container.Add(new XElement(style1.Item1));

                //Apply attribute reference
                var styleId2 = firstCell2.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "StyleID");

                if (styleId2 == null) {
                    firstCell2.Add(new XAttribute(firstCell1.Attributes().First(a =>  a.Name.LocalName == "StyleID")));
                }
                else
                {
                    styleId2.Value = style1.Item2;
                }


                range2.set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet, doc2.GetString());

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static Tuple<XElement, string> GetStyleForCell(XElement cell, XDocument document)
        {
            var styleId = cell.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "StyleID")?.Value ?? "Default";
            return new Tuple<XElement, string>(GetStyleById(document, styleId), styleId);
        }

        private static XElement GetStyleById(XDocument document, string styleId)
        {
            var styles = document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.LocalName == "Styles").Elements().Where(s => s.Name.LocalName == "Style");
            var style = styles.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName == "ID")?.Value == styleId);
            return style;
        }
    }

    public static class XDocumentEx
    {
        //This method makes sure nothing has happened with the formatting of the XML
        public static string GetString(this XDocument doc)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
            {
                doc.Save(writer);
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```